# Find ID of User to add to another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to retrieve the ID of the user from the User table in order to pass the id to the metadata field of the File table. Within the model of the file table I added the relation `belongs to :user`. When the User uploads a file a record is created in the File table. As a result of this I have also added `after_create :update_metadata' to update the metadata field.`

Within the 'update_metadata' method I need to find a way to grab the user ID and pass it into the metadata field when a File is uploaded. I assumed `user_id = User.find(id) update_attribute(:metadata, user_id)` would work but nothing is displayed in the metadata field.

I expected the field to be updated with the User's ID.

Comment: If the answers didn't solve your problem, post your creation code, please!

Comment: I really hope you didn't name your model `File`. That's an exceptionally bad choice as it clashes with the [Ruby core class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added the association in file model as:

```
belongs_to :user
```

There must be a user_id present in file object in the database determining which user it belongs to.

So you can access that by `file_object.user_id` or `file_object.user.id`

Note: In the after_create callback you can access your file object directly or by using `self` keyword

Comment: Thank You! I passed in by using file.user_id. This took the ID from the user's table and placed in within metadata field on the File table when a file was added/created.